Wrong normalized smoothing kernels provided in paper?
Consider following smoothing kernel
$$W_{Spiky}\left(r,\ h\right)\ =\ \frac{15}{\pi\cdot h^{6}}\left\{0\le r\le h:\left(h-r\right)^{3},\ 0\right\}$$
taken from the paper https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/sca03.pdf.
That kernel is used for pressure calculation and is said to be normalized.
But when integrating that formula from 0 to h, I dont get 1 (as I would expect when it was normalized).
The normalized formula seems to be
$$W_{SpikyNormed}\left(r,\ h\right)\ =\ \frac{4}{h^{4}}\left\{0\le r\le h:\left(h-r\right)^{3},\ 0\right\}$$
I just integrated the function
$$\left(h-r\right)^{3}$$
from 0 to h and divided that function by the result.
Have the authors mistaken something? Or am I mistaken their words?

I don't have the knowledge for answer your question, but I want to ask you if you already writen this question to the authors?... its against all odds but I have received answers when asking for it even when I am nobody for other researchers.... researchers got excited when someone else is reading their papers, so you could try it (contact them directly)... just be polite but short (2 lines at much).

@Joako Unfortunately, no email is provided and since I don't have linked in nor access to research gate, it will be more or less difficult to establish correspondence.

I see... maybe try by looking other papers from the same author... but in my experience, I have already found mistakes in papers, sometimes happen when the editor mistakes something and the authors don't realize it... could be a sign change, that change everything (which was the case I found)

It's a 3D kernel. As such, its normalization is $$\int_0^hW(r,h),4\pi r^2dr=1.$$

@Gonçalo .. yes, makes sense indeed. In 2d it would be $2\pi\int_{0}^{h}W\left(r,\ h\right)\cdot r\ dr$ I guess?

Yes, indeed. ${}{}$

@Gonçalo Thanks. I am currently reading the following document: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs5220-f11/code/sph-derive.pdf
In section 2 "Smoothing kernels" the author gives an intuition to the smoothing kernel.
In that, the author writes: $q=\left|\frac{bfr}{h}\right|$ Any idea what b stands for, and espacially what f*r means?

It seems that "bfr" is a typo. I suspect that the author intended to write  $\bf{r}$ (boldface r), but missed the backslash in the Latex command "\bf{r}".
